# set a variable in one class use in another class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am using two bean classes employee and admin.I have set the variable empid in employee class using employee class object.I want to set that employee class object(emp) to admin class.but i'm getting null pointer exception on empid field.

```
    emp.setEmpid(eid);
    ad.setCourseid(cid);
    ad.setCoursename(cname);
    ad.setParticipants(participants);
    ad.setEmployee(emp);
```

**Employee**

```
package entity;





public class Employee 
{

    private int empid;
    private String empname;
    private String password;
    private String designation;
    private String domain;
    private String role;

    private String head;
    private String specialist;

    public int getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }
    public void setEmpid(int empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }
    public String getEmpname() {
        return empname;
    }
    public void setEmpname(String empname) {
        this.empname = empname;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }
    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }
    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }
    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
    public String getHead() {
        return head;
    }
    public void setHead(String head) {
        this.head = head;
    }
    public String getSpecialist() {
        return specialist;
    }
    public void setSpecialist(String specialist) {
        this.specialist = specialist;
    }
}
```

**Admin**

```
package entity;
public class Admin {

    private int courseid;
    private String coursename;
    private int participants;
    private Employee employee;

public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }
    public void setEmployee(Employee empid) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
public int getCourseid() {

        return courseid;
    }
    public void setCourseid(int courseid) {

        this.courseid = courseid;

    }
    public String getCoursename() {
        return coursename;
    }
    public void setCoursename(String coursename) {
        this.coursename = coursename;
    }
    public int getParticipants() {
        return participants;
    }
    public void setParticipants(int participants) {
        this.participants = participants;
    }
}
```

Actually i want to insert that empid in database as a foreign key but due to null pointer exception i can't do that.

Comment: Where do you get the exception and which line? The code only shows you  that you are adding employee object - `emp.setEmpid(eid);ad.setEmployee(emp);`

Comment: Please add entire bean class.

Comment: @M.prabhu use cachemanager or hashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look here , in your admin class you are doing something like this

```
public void setEmployee(Employee empid) {
        this.employee = employee;
}
```

this is like empty assignment, you are assigning employee to employee which doesnt have any effect, invariably you are assigning null value to null value as Default for object is null

do it like

```
public void setEmployee(Employee empid) {
       this.employee = empid;
}
```